# Looking for a Event Calender for Jquery / Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, calendar

I am looking for a Event Calender.
It should do exactly this:
http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/

The problem is, the linked calender is without any futher explanation how to insert data, So nay ideas?

Comment: Quick look at the page seems it expects a JSON encoded object to be the point of it's data. it seems to make an ajax request to get the data back to the file location you specify in `eventsjson:'path/to/my/controller.ext'`. There are 5 possible properties it seems. `{'date': null, 'description': null, 'title': null, 'type': null, 'url': null},{'date': null, 'description': null, 'title': null, 'type': null, 'url': null},{'date': null, 'description': null, 'title': null, 'type': null, 'url': null}` and so on.

Comment: By the way -- quick read through the comments on that page point out that he uses a unix time stamp for the date format, so you'll need to ensure your date is formatted appropriately coming from your asp controller.

Comment: Thanks, its hard for me to get this things, I never used json. Do you wanna help me with this?

Comment: I'm not an ASP Developer, I'm a PHP developer, but a quick google took me to [http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/) which shows how simple it is to make an dreturn json.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a little overkill, but you could try [Extjs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) from [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/).

They have a demo of a calendar [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/calendar/index.html)